# Create two subsets of data such that each subset has equal proportion of classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I have a beginner in python and machine learning. I have a dataset of 30k+ observations and highly imbalanced. I have to create two subsets of data such that first subset contain 92% of success records and 8% of failure records and same applies to the second subset, given that these two sets contribute to 70-30 of the overall dataset.

len(data)=30k

subset1= 70% of 30k such that it contains (92% of success records and 8% of failure records)

subset1= 30% of 30k such that it contains (92% of success records and 8% of failure records)

This is for binary classification. These subset1 and subset2 are to be used for train and test datasets as per business.

Comment: Check [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) from scikit learn

Comment: This can divide data into 70-30 split but we cannot guarantee that each set will have equal proportions of data-spread(92-8%).

Comment: All you need is split the dataset to 92% of success and 8% of failure, then use 70-30 train test split on both datasets, then combine and shuffle the success-train and success-test.

Answer (score 0):

Without having access to the dataset, I can give you some guidelines as how to do this,

- Divide original dataframe (df) into success (df_s) and failure records (df_f)
- df1 and df2 will each contain 15k records from df
- using [pandas.DataFrame.Sample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) extract 0.92 records from df_s and 0.8 records from df_f and put them in df1
- whatever is remaining in df_s and df_f goes into df2 (Note: you might need to play around with this last step depending upon your data)